# Cognos 10.2 Using row values in prompt to filter another prompt

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I am new to Cognos and wondering how or if possible to achieve the following.

Firstly, I have a table:

```
Period Id     Name  Start_Date     End_Date

1             a     01/04/2011     06/08/2013
```

I can create a prompt to select the *Period Id* from the scheme and pass it through, but I would like now to prefill a second prompt with *Start_Date* and *End_Date* of the *Period Id* selected in the first prompt:

```
Scheme Start_date <= Period.Start_Date where ID = selected Period ID from ?Period Prompt?
Scheme End_date <= Period.End_Date where ID = selected Period ID from ?Period Prompt?
```

I cannot use an SQL connection, so I cannot build the SQL separately eg:

```
select Start, End from....Where ....= ?Prompt?
```

Thank you in advance....

Roger

Comment: Even if you are not allowed to use SQL directly do you have access to a) the Framework Manager model or b) the DB schema to install a DB view?

Comment: HI Marcus, Yes I have access to the schema and framework manager. What I meant to say is that I am not allowed to open extra connections to the SQL server.  I know how to extract the information using SQL but I am not allowed to add a permanent solution incorporating a specific connection outside of the reports package.

Comment: Then you should be able to establish a relationship between the *Period Id* chosen in the first prompt and the Period entity containing *Start_Date* and *End_Date*. In the query for the second prompt you can filter for the *Id* value chosen in the first prompt. Cognos takes care of the rest.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I havent had time to go back to this job , next week  I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create [Cascading Prompts.](https://www2.kent.edu/is/resources/training/upload/cascading-prompt.pdf)

Create two prompts.  The first links to a parameter, lets call it Parameter1.

Your second prompt has a Cascading Source set to Parameter1.  When creating the the second prompt, you have the option to create a 'Parameterized Filter'.  Use that option to set what value is being filtered, and point it at parameter1.

[Here is an example from IBM.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-pp-reporting-scripting_techniques-page673/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I havent had time to go back to this job , next week  I will give it a try.